# jQuery UI Tooltip Widget remove title attribute

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, tooltip

I try use jQuery UI Tooltip Widget but i find some problem for me. If the tooltip is open, it removes title attribute on element over which it opened. How i can fix this?
I try something like this:

```
<div class="spbin" title="NAME"><div class="ptmd aud" title="LINK"></div></div>
```

Script:

```
$('[title]').tooltip({
open:function(){var te=$('.ui-tooltip-content').html();
$(this).attr('title',te);}},
{show:{effect:'slideDown',delay:250}},
{hide:{effect:'explode',delay:250}},
{track:true});
```

But it not halp's me (

Comment: Why do you want to do this? I expect it does this to prevent the browser from displaying the title while the tooltip is displaying.

Comment: These attributes are used to another script. This example work well for one div & title element but not work if its more then one.

Comment: You shouldn't use title attributes for your own purposes. Put the information in a `data-XXX` attribute instead.

Comment: You are right, it does this to prevent the browser from displaying the title while the tooltip is displaying

Comment: Ok! I will try to do as you suggest

Comment: value will already be stored in element data by plugin also

Comment: I had a similar question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14926878/changing-the-title-attribute-using-jquery-while-hovering-over-the-element

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did as advised Barmar. It worked. No longer need to return the value of the attribute title. I used the following code:

```
<div class="spbin" data-n="NAME">
     <div class="ptmd aud" data-l="LINK"></div>
</div>
<div class="tlv"></div>
```

Script:

```
$('[title]').tooltip(
    {show:{effect:'slideDown',delay:250}},
    {hide:{effect:'explode',delay:250}},
    {track:true}
);

$('.spbin').each(function(){
    $('.tlv',this).text(this.dataset.n);
    $(this).attr('title',this.dataset.n);
    $(this).hide();
    $(this).delay(du*2).fadeIn(du);
});
```

Thank you again Barmar!