# Changing the title attribute using jQuery while hovering over the element

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, tooltip, jquery-ui-tooltip

I have div button that has a title attribute that us used as the text for tool tips using jQueryUI. I would like to change the tooltip of the button by clicking it. However, when the button is clicked and the call back function is fired, the mouse is over the div and title is null.

How do I go about fixing this behaviour? It looks like jQueryUI Tooltip widget removes the title on hover and puts it back on mouse out.

```
$( document ).tooltip();
$(".btn").click(function(){
    alert($(this).attr("title")); // Expect to see T1 or T2 but shows blank
    if ($(this).attr("title")=="T1"){
        $(this).attr("title","T2")
    }else{
        $(this).attr("title","T1")
    }
});
```

Live: http://jsfiddle.net/lordloh/ckTjA/

Without the jQueryUI Tooltip widget in place, things seem to work fine : http://jsfiddle.net/lordloh/ckTjA/1/

Moreover, I have the tooltip widget applied on `$(document)`. So I cannot use `$(this).tooltip("option","content")` as the tooltip is not applied on `$(this)` explicitly. This results in a Javascript error on the console.

2013-02-18: As of now, I am running `$(document).tooltip("destroy");`, changing title attributes and `$(document).tooltip();`. Not an elegant solution :-( I am looking for something that is not a hack.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The widget removes the text from the `title` attribute to prevent the native browser tooltip from appearing. When it removes the text, it stores it in data attached to the element.

You can do the same using this line of code:

```
$("#my-element").data("ui-tooltip-title", "My new tooltip message");
```

Now, if the user moves their mouse away from the element, and then hovers back onto it, it will show the new text.

To show the new text immediately, you need to update the live tooltip overlay element, which thankfully is easy to find. You just need to do this after you've updated the text:

```
$(".ui-tooltip-content").html($("#my-element").data("ui-tooltip-title"));
```

<sub>Tested on jQuery UI 1.10.0.</sub>

Comment: Thanks. Why can't I access it through `$(this).attr("data-ui-tooltip-title")` ?

Comment: I see two entries in the docs - http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/ and http://api.jquery.com/data/. The latter seems to be using the HTML5 attribute `data-*`. I assume that the `$("#my-element").data("ui-tooltip-title")` is storing the data elsewhere(?).

Comment: I think jQuery only stores info in the HTML5 `data-xxx` if the element has the data attribute to start with. If it doesn't then it stores it in an internal array or something like that.

Answer (score 2):

When using the tooltip widget, you can update the contents via its own API:

```
    $(this).tooltip('option', 'content', "New Content Goes Here");
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not seem to work on `$(this)` as I have set the tooltip on `document`.

Comment: @LordLoh. well maybe you should do it differently :-)

Comment: As of now, I am running `$(document).tooltip("destroy");`, changing title attributes and `$(document).tooltip();`. Not an elegant solution :-(

Comment: @LordLoh. yes I agree - well I think maybe the "items" command may be what you need; I'm not that familiar with that widget as I think I've only used it once, a long time ago, but I *think* that the "items" command paired with "content" lets you pick which elements to affect.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

> $('document').ready(function() { $( 'document' ).tooltip();
>   $(".btn").click(function(){
>       alert($(this).attr("title"));
>       if ($(this).attr("title")=="T1"){
>           $(this).attr("title","T2"); 
>       }else{
>           $(this).attr("title","T1");
>       } 
>     }); 
>   });  $( 'document' ) should be in single or double quotes(' or ") and it works *fine* for me **whitout** $( 'document'
>   ).tooltip();